# MYSQL No duplicate Rows - Many-to-Many Hierarchy with Multiple Parents

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create hierarchy result set. Sample records in the table.
In the below output I don't have parents name in the second column (root), likewise, I have 22 parents ( roots! without super parents).

```
Child Name Parent
-----------------
1     A    1-3 
2     B    1-3
3     C    1-3
1-3   D    1-10
3-5   E    1-10
6-10  F    1-10
1-10  G   1-100
201   w   200-210
202   x   200-210
203   y   200-210
200-210 z 200-300
```

My Code: Here I have written the Mysql join query 3 times to get 4 levels.

```
SELECT 
t1.Child ,
t1.Name ,
t2.Child ,
t2.Name ,
t3.Child ,
t3.Name,
t4.Child ,
t4.Name
FROM
code t1
left join code  t2 on  t1.Child = t2.Parent
left join code  t3 on  t2.Child  = t3.Parent
left join code  t4 on  t3.Child = t4.Parent
```

Output:

```
t1.Child t1.Name t2.Child t2.Name t3.Child t3.Name t4.Child t4.Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------   
1-100    root    1-10        G   1-3       D            1    A 
1-100    root    1-10        G   1-3       D            1    B
1-100    root    1-10        G   1-3       D            1    C
1-10      G      1-3       D       1       A
1-10      G      1-3       D       1       B
1-10      G      1-3       D       1       C
1-3       D      1         A
1-3       D      1         B
1-3       D      1         C
200-300   root  200-210    z     201       w 
200-300   root  200-210    z     202       x 
200-300   root  200-210    z     203       y 
200-210    z     201       w 
200-210    z     202       x 
200-210    z     203       y
```

I was just wanted line 1 to 3 & 10 - 12,

I'm looking for the rows like from

Grand Parents1(Root) to Grand Children's

Grand Parents2(Root) to Grand Children's

but not line 4 - 9 & 13 - 15 because the information is duplicated I have this information in already in col 3,4,5,6....etc

I don't want rows again to be duplicated

Excepted Output:

```
t1.Child t1.Name t2.Child t2.Name t3.Child t3.Name t4.Child t4.Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------   
1-100    root    1-10        G   1-3       D            1    A 
1-100    root    1-10        G   1-3       D            1    B
1-100    root    1-10        G   1-3       D            1    C
200-300   root  200-210    z     201       w 
200-300   root  200-210    z     202       x 
200-300   root  200-210    z     203       y
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  You can use `exists` in a `where` clause:

```
SELECT t1.Child, t1.Name, t2.Child, t2.Name,
       t3.Child, t3.Name, t4.Child, t4.Name
FROM code t1 LEFT JOIN
     code t2 on t1.Child = t2.Parent LEFT JOIN
     code t3 on t2.Child = t3.Parent LEFT JOIN
     code t4 on t3.Child = t4.Parent
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM code c
                  WHERE c.Child = t1.Parent
                 );
```

This will return only the rows that start with a root.

In your case, you could also more simply do:

```
WHERE t1.Name = 'root'
```

If you prefer.

Comment: Gordon, Please explain me where clause not exist part.

Thanks So Much

Comment: @max Please read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: @max . . . The `where` clause ensures that the rows selected are only for `t1` records that have no parent.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.. Appreciate your help